# OpenCV Construct Mat from float* array

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, constructor, mat

I am trying to use the OpenCV Mat::Mat constructor with the option of passing in data.

I have read on this forum that you can pass in a float pointer to an array, but every time I do that it tries to pass in the address (I think that is what is happening) rather than the actual values from the array.

I have tried two different way of creating the float array:

```
float *outputimg = (float*)malloc(img1.rows*img1.cols*sizeof(float));
```

and

```
float *outputimg = (float*)malloc(img1.step*img1.elemSize());
```

then I have tried the Mat constructor as follows:

```
Mat contrastimg(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_32F, outputimg, img1.step);

Mat contrastimg(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_32F, outputimg);

Mat contrastimg(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_32F, outputimg, img1.cols*sizeof(float));
```

none of these are working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: your 2nd try should work with the first float array... how did you test whether it works?!?

Comment: Mat contrastimg(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_32F, floatptr); is the valid one.

Answer (score -2):

I think, the best way to do what you need is to first [convert](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#CvMat) your pointer to `CvMat` matrix and then [construct](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat::Mat(const%20CvMat*%20m,%20bool%20copyData)) a `Mat` object from it. It should look something like this:

```
CvMat* m = new CvMat;
m->type = yourType;
m->data.fl = outputimg;
m->rows = img1.rows;
m->cols = img1.cols;

Mat matrix(m);
```

Comment: A slight improvement would be to not use `new`, and simply create the `CvMat m;` Then you don't risk leaking it, and can create the `Mat`: `Mat matrix(&m);`.